# Installing Ubuntu Server 18.04

Tags: vmware, downloads

I downloaded Ubuntu 18.04 and a bunch of folders are seen. What do I click on to install it after I download it?

Answer (score 1):

You should download appropriate ISO image first.
Then create a bootable USB stick with the help of an external program or simply burn image to cd.
Now you can try to boot from USB and install. The process is very simple and most of the time is automated, you should only select several options during setup process i.e. don't forget to select install is openness.